# Ie8 calculates offset and hack fix breaks ie9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

For some reason IE8 calculates an offset of `18px` on a CSS element.

When I add a `top: -18px` and `left: -8px` it fixes the issue in IE8 but breaks it in every other browser.

I tried adding hacks like the `\9` and `\0/` but those do not work in IE9.

Adding the `\9` after the `top` and `left` attributes fix IE8.

However, IE9 does not seem to recognize the hack and uses the negative `top` and `left` values and the layout breaks.

I need a way to fix this but it needs to be something I can do in the CSS only.

This is just a small menu which is used all over the place in a much larger Java project and I do not have access to the rest of the code. Only to the CSS.

Here is the CSS class that is getting the offset:

```
#myMenuBar{
        position: relative;
        width:800px;
        height:auto !important;
        height:36px;
        margin:0 auto;
        z-index:3001;
        text-align:left;
        top: 0px;  
        left: 0px;

    }
```

Like I said, changing the top and left to -18px and -8px respectively fixes the issue in ie8 but breaks it everywhere else since ie8 is the only browser which calculates this offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE conditional comments so that it only applies to IE8 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<style type="text/css">
#myMenuBar{
    position: relative;
    width:800px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:36px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:3001;
    text-align:left;
    top: 0px;  
    left: 0px;
}
</style>


<!--[if IE 8]>     
<style type="text/css">
/* These will override the values above in IE 8 only */
#myMenuBar {
    top: -18px;  
    left: -8px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If you can't modify the HTML, you can use CSS hacks to target IE8 and below http://www.gravitationalfx.com/css-hacks-for-ie-targeting-only-ie8-ie7-and-ie6/ Just don't tell anybody I suggested you use it ;)

```
#myMenuBar{
    position: relative;
    width:800px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:36px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:3001;
    text-align:left;
    top: 0;  
    left: 0;
    /* That crap at the end makes it work in < IE8 only */
    top: -18px\9;
    left: -18px\9;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. Unfortunately that doesn't work. The conditional doesn't appear to be executed when placed in the css page. In other words, looking at the code above, if I examine the myMenuBar element in ie8 dev tools it shows top: 0px, left: 0px not the values which are in the if statement.

Comment: @user1771971 You have to use the code as I specified, not within the CSS file, that's why I posted the full example. Posting a really nasty hack you can use in the CSS files in a second

Comment: AS I noted originally, I don't have access to the HTML pages so any fix I would use would need to be in the css. I already tried the \9 hack. Doesn't work in ie9. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it

```
#myMenuBar{
    position: relative;
    width:800px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:36px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:3001;
    text-align:left;
    top: -18px;
    left: -8px;
}

:root #myMenuBar { top: 0px; \0/IE9; left: 0px; \0/IE9;}  /* IE9 + IE10pp4 */
```

This seems to work correctly in ie8, 9 firefox, safari and chrome.